# onclick button should apply disable mode to div using css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

onclick on button class "dis-able" i need to make class check to apply the disable mode styles.Issue should be solved only in css but not in js

```
.dis-able:active .check
{
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity:0.5;
    background-color:pink !important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nikhila/037rL2bo/2/

Comment: can you give an example of what you want ?

Comment: Unfortunately, CSS doesn't work like that and is not what it is intended for. You will require javascript. Also, the way you have structured your DOM will not make those selectors valid.